# Rails 3.1 - Getting results between start and end dates?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an event listing site where i'm currently listing events occuring `today` by doing:

```
def load_today_events
 @today_events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['start_date =?', Date.today])
end
```

This works perfectly well.

I've recently introduced an `end_date` for events spanning more than one day.

Obviously, with the above code once the `start_date` has passed the event disappears from my listing.

I may be having a mental block here, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to show events that's start date has passed but end date has not.

I think I want something along the lines of:

**find events where `date.today` is equal to or between `start_date` or `end_date`**

Any ideas how best to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand this correctly, but here are some examples of what you can do with dates.
In the example below, `current_date` is a `postgresql` function for the today date. This would match the events that the current_date is bigger or equal than start_date and less than end_date.

```
@today_events = Event.where("current_date >=  ? and current_date <= ?", start_date, end_date)
```

Another approach could be like this:

```
@today_events = Event.where("start_date >=  ? and end_date <= ?", start_date, end_date)
```

This example shows events that are from a current date interval.
This is the basics, so i hope you can apply to your own problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's been a great help.